# Display an uploaded image, and scale it to fit the image field without distortion

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image

I have used the script below to display an uploaded image without having to reload the page, and it works perfectly.

Except for scaling the uploaded image to fit a 390px x 390px img object.

If I can set the background image to be the uploaded file, css will nicely scale the image, but the current method simply stretched the src image to fill the entire field.

How can I modify this function to apply the `e.target.result` to the background Image rather than the src?

```
//function to display selected image
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            //$('#optimageinput').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
    $('#optimageinput').css('background-image', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')');
};
```

Comment: Perfect!!!! Thanks. I knew it had to be simple, just couldn't get the syntax right.